# How to dynamically rebind datasource of a Kendo MultiSelectFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

Hi I have a perfectly working kendo MultiSelectFor **ddlExplainingPractitioner** that only starts querying when user input at least 2 characters to search for user name. However, I'm trying to find a way to rebind the data source based on the selection of another dropdownlist **ddlDivision**. When **ddlDivision**'s selection changes from the client side, **ddlExplainingPractitioner**'s data source will also need to change.

**ddlExplainingPractitioner**

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(model => model.ExplainingPractitionerId)
.Name("ExplainingPractitionerId")
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%;" })
.Filter(FilterType.Contains)
.Placeholder("Select Explaining Practitioner...")
.AutoBind(false)
.Animation(false)
.MinLength(2)
.MaxSelectedItems(1)
.DataSource(source =>
{
    source.Read(read =>
    {
        
        read.Action("GetExplainingPractitioners", "CommonJsonActions");
    })
    .ServerFiltering(true);
})
.DataValueField("MemberId")
.DataTextField("DisplayName")
.BindTo(Model.ExplainingPractitioners)
.Value(Model.ExplainingPractitioners)
)
```

Ajax script to call another data source

```
function getPsychiatrist() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: "/CommonJsonActions/GetPsychiatrists",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        beforeSend: function () {
            alert('In beforeSend');
        },
        success: function (result) {
            alert('Success');
            var resultData = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                resultData.push({ MemberId: result[i].MemberId, DisplayName: result[i].DisplayName });
            }

            $ddlExplainingPractitioner.kendoMultiSelect({
                dataTextField: "DisplayName",
                dataValueField: "MemberId",
                dataSource: resultData,
                optionLabel: "Select Explaining Practitioner...",
                autoClose: false
            });
        }
    })
}
```

script inside the **ddlDivision** toggle

```
getPsychiatrist();
$ddlExplainingPractitioner.data("kendoMultiSelect").dataSource.read();
```

What I can confirm now is when I toggle **ddlDivision**, debug does route me to the function GetPsychiatrists, and it is getting all the data. However I'm still seeing the same data coming from **ddlExplainingPractitioner**. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found the issue, I need to call a reload in success.
However, I have to disable the filter Contains functionality in order for this to work.

Also I'm calling the full list, which is not ideal.

Anyone has better idea on how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Once you get a reference to the ExplainingPractitionerId MultiSelect you can use the [setDataSource method](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/multiselect/methods/setdatasource) and set new kendo.data.DataSource for its DataSource. Populate this new instance with the data from your ajax call.